# How to figure out the VAT and print it

Tags: c#

I am coding a simple program that takes a price and include a VAT in this price. What i want is to print also the VAT before include it in the price. So the "customer" can see the price and the VAT apart, so the output in for example will be this:

```
Price: 20 with 23% VAT
VAT: 4,6
Total price: 24,6
```

and then include the VAT in the price. One part of my code so far is this:

```
double price = 20;
double total_price = 0;

total_price = price +price * 0.23;
```

Comment: `price * 0.23` - there's your VAT.

Comment: First change `double` to `decimal` then round VAT to 2 decimal places Math.Round(a, 2)

Comment: DO NOT USE double for money values. Use DECIMAL

Comment: About rounding I was mistaken, since we talk about money you must check law of your country to find you what rounding algorithm you may use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Vat ="+ price* 0.23);
Console.WriteLine("Price ="+ price);
Console.WriteLine("Total price with VAT ="+ (price + price* 0.23));
```

Adding this to your solution should do it.